# Facebook Graph API can't fetch "verified" profile data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can't seem to get the key/value pair for verified when using the graph API, I know that verified needs an access token, my code is as follows.

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => '1234',
        'secret' => '567',
    ));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if ($user) {
try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api("/$user/?access_token=$token");

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
}
```

$user_profile never has the verified data in it. Any ideas?

Comment: With php sdk you don't need to pass `access_token` manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ride of `$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();`

Change:

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's how I had it originally and it seems to work with my normal facebook account, but when I tried it with a different account verified doesn't show up at all. But it sounds like this is the right code. Its probably an issue with the testing account.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the PHP SDK, you don't need to pass the access token as it's passed for you. Additionally, you don't need the user ID, you can just use `/me`:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api("/me");
```

Make sure you have authenticated your app too - I don't see that happening here, although it may happen somewhere else that you're not showing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to do:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api("/$user/?access_token=$token");
```

You can however do:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api("/me");
```